# MongoDb y node js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo una aplicacion hecha en **reactjs**, manejo las dependencias con **nodejs** y quiero conectarme a una base de datos que tengo instalada localmente.

instale express y mongodb usando npm.

me genera este error al levantar la aplicacion:

> Module not found: 'module' in C:\Proyectos\ZarateAlarmas\zaw\node_modules\requir
>   @ ./~/require_optional/~/resolve-from/index.js 3:13-30

y mi codigo es :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animals', function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        db.collection('mammals').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com), es muy fácil de usar, y te permite mapear los modelos.

```
let Model = require('./models/model');
Model.find({},function(err,data){
//handle error and data
});
```